# Zoom Image with child div

Tags: zooming, marker

I want to keep child div how it was in before of zoom. I want to zoom image like that https://yeye0922.github.io/ZoomMarker/
but when I zoom image child element is going away from coordinate.

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
    var w = parseInt($("#parent").css("width").replace("px",""));
    var h = parseInt($("#parent").css("height").replace("px",""));
    var chilTop = parseInt($("#child2").css("top").replace("px",""));
    var chilLeft = parseInt($("#child2").css("left").replace("px",""));

    var a  =  w / chilLeft;
    var b  =  h / chilTop;
    var aa = chilLeft / a;
    var bb = chilTop / b;
    $("#child2").css("top",chilTop + aa +"px");
    $("#child2").css("left",chilLeft + bb +"px");
    w = w + 100;
    h = h + 100;
    $("#parent").css("height",h);
    $("#parent").css("width",w);

})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Etibar2/8hu57efo/

anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is modifying the top and left coordinates in the lines of

```
    $("#child2").css("top",chilTop + aa +"px");
    $("#child2").css("left",chilLeft + bb +"px");
```

Just remove them or comment them out.

Comment: In this case child div is going to top of div .I want to zoom image with child div

Comment: @Etibar you are welcome. If it solved your problem, you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: it didn't solve my problem.I just thanked for your answer

Comment: @Etibar I do not have enough context of your problem to understand what your problem is. The problem was that the div has gone away from the coordinate. This was solved. You mentioned that child div is going to top of div. I do not know top of what div it is going, whether it is a problem or not and what do you want to achieve in general. A better description of the problem, which would clarify what is your goal and how is the current attempt failing would help me to help you.

Comment: I want to keep child div "#child2" in same field when div is zooming 100 px;. Same field how child div was in image

Comment: @Etibar what do you mean by keeping #child2 in the same field when div is zooming? Same field as what? What does keeping it in the field mean here? I am afraid I still do not understand the problem. You will need to explain it, as in the current state of affairs I cannot help you, since the problem is unclear.